Finding simpler ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(Y^2 - X, X+1)$
Let $L = \mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(Y^2 - X, X+1)$ be given. I want to check if $L$ is
an integral domain or even a field.
I tried the following approach:
In $L$ it holds that $X + 1 = 0$ and $Y^2 - X = 0$ so $X = -1$ and $Y^2 = X = -1 \Rightarrow Y = \sqrt{-1} = i$.
So try to constuct an isomorphismen based on this knowledge:
$\varphi: \mathbb{R}[X,Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: f(X,Y) \mapsto f(-1, i)$
$\varphi$ clearly is an homomorphismen and surjective because $aX + bY \mapsto -a + bi$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Further the kernel of $\varphi$ includes $X + 1$ because $-1 + 1 = 0$ and $Y^2 - X$ because $i^2 - (-1 ) = 0$. From the definition of a homomorphismen it follows that
$a(X,Y) \cdot (X + 1) + b(X,Y) \cdot (Y^2 - X)$ with $a,b \in R[X,Y]$ is also included in the kernel, therefore $\ker \varphi = (X + 1, Y^2 - X)$.
Now apply the homomorphism theorem for rings and you get an isomorphismen $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(Y^2 - X, X+1) \simeq \mathbb{C}$
Is this argumentation correct? Is the approach I took somehow flawed / are there hidden pitfalls? Appreciate anybody giving feedback!

Perhaps you want $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(Y^2-X,X+1)$ so that you're quotienting by the ideal $(Y^2-X,X+1)$?  It looks like you're missing the slash.

a sorry, of course that's what i mean

I think you've proved that $(X+1, Y^2-X) \subseteq \ker \varphi$, but I don't think you've proved the reverse inclusion.

First rewrite $L$ as $\mathbb{R}[Y]/(Y^2+1)$. Can you show that $Y^2+1$ is irreducible and therefore defines a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[Y]$?

f(Y) = Y^2 + 1 is irreducible in R[Y] because it only has complex roots f(Y) = (Y - i)(Y + i) and it is of degree 2 so factors would need to be of degree 1

@RobertShore I see, I have to proof that for every $f \in \ker \varphi$ it holds that $f = a(X,Y)(X+1) + b(X,Y)(Y^2 - X)$. I'm currently not exactly sure how. Do you have any tips?

@Exitpath Now to show that $I = (Y^2 + 1)$ is a maximal ideal, you can assume another polynomial $g(Y) \in \mathbb{R}[Y]$ such that $(Y^2 + 1)  \cdot h(Y) \neq g(Y)$ for any $h(Y) \in \mathbb{R}[Y]$, in short $g(Y)$ is not included in the ideal $I$. Now because $Y^2 + 1$ is irreducable in $\mathbb{R}[Y]$ there is no non constant polynominal that divides it, so it follows with $\mathbb{R}[Y]$ euclidian domain that $\gcd(Y^2 + 1, g(Y)) = (1)$ so $(Y^2 + 1, g(Y)) = (1) = \mathbb{R}[Y]$. Hence $(Y^2 + 1)$ is maximal.

And because $I$ is maximal $\mathbb{R}[Y]/I$ is an field.

@Xanda Once you know your ring is a field, what do you know about homomorphisms from it to another ring, say $\mathbb{C}$? Equivalently, do you see now how to get past Robert Shore’s objection?

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque sorry, i will consider this in the future

@Exitpath I know that an homomorphism between fields has to be injective, but I'm not entirely sure how to see that an homomorphism starting in $\mathbb{R}[Y]/I$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is surjectiv.

Instead I think you can conclude using homomorphism theorem like this:
Given the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}[Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : f(Y) \mapsto f(i)$ it is clearly surjective because of $Yb + a$. Further $i^2 + 1 = 0$ so included in the kernel, therefore $I \subseteq \ker \phi$ but $I$ is maximal as shown, so it already has to be $I = \ker \phi$ because $\ker \phi \neq \mathbb{R}[Y]$. Finally by homomorphism theorem we can conclude $\mathbb{R}[Y]/I \simeq \mathbb{C}$.

You only prove that $(X+1,Y^2-X)$ is contained in the kernel. This is not enough. But you don't need to bother to do any calculation here: Your proof started in a very good way. You can complete it using universal properties.
Namely, $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(Y^2-X,X+1)$ is the universal commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra containing two elements $x,y$ satisfying the relations $y^2-x=0$ and $x+1=0$. This is equivalent to $y^2=x$ and $x=-1$. So we may just erase $x$ from the data, just keep $y$. Then we have the universal commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra containing an element $y$ with $y^2=-1$. And that is $\mathbb{R}[Y]/(Y^2+1) = \mathbb{C}$.
The advantage of this method is that you can immediately generalize it to determine other quotients.

+1. I would only object that it may not be obvious to a beginner that $\mathbb{C}$ is the universal real algebra with an element squaring to $-1$. So it’s still useful to construct an explicit map from the quotient to the complex numbers

No. This answer of course has universal properties as a prerequisite, and therefore it has to be known that $\mathbb{R}[Y]/(Y^2+1)$ is the universal commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra with an element $y$ with $y^2+1=0$. And then you only need to verify -- which is much easier than the original problem -- that $\mathbb{R}[Y]/(Y^2+1) = \mathbb{C}$ (what I also write in my answer). And for this, one directly verifies that $\mathbb{C}$ has the desired universal property.

Unfortunately, cosets obscure what quotients are really about. Beginners should be told what they are really about, so that they don't get lost in useless calculations (fundamental 'theorem' on homomorphisms = universal property of a quotient = definition of the quotient).

Please do not answer SV questions that are off-topic (cf. comment on question).
